# Change Breadcrumb For FishPig Wordpress

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs, blog

On the posts page of my FishPig Wordpress blog, my Breadcrumb says Home > Blog. I want to change that to news.

I haven't been able to find where that's being set. I checked the database and the site name, but it's not coming from either of them.

I don't have any SEO tools installed on the blog.

Thanks